# activated something accidentally while animating armature, puts keys on every bone instead of just one I'm animating

Tags: animation, armature

In one file while animating armature I have done something and don't know what....
Basically, when animating one bone it puts keys on all the bones, where in other file I can animate same armature a bone at a time. Can't figure out what I have turned on or off, some accidental shortcut, I'm relatively new to blender and it's my first time animating armature in it.

- Just noticed it only does it when duplicating keys with 'Shift+D', it duplicated keys for all the bones.